# Selectizejs: dynamically generated select elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I have an html `<select></select>` element . When I press `add`, a duplicate select element gets generated using Jquery.

```
$(document).on("click", ".add_member", function () {
    $('.color').selectize({
        plugins: ['remove_button'],
        persist: true,
        maxItems: 1,
    });
})
```

I must call it like so, otherwise `selectize` function wouldn't get called. The problem is that each time I press `add`, the previously selected item disappear and selectize is reset to null.

Comment: You might want to change the `.color` selector to something that is specific to the element you just added. Otherwise the `selectize()` function will be called on all elements with class `.color`. Can you maybe post full code? Or is this your full code? Where / how are you adding your new <select> element?

Comment: @RensTillmann this is my full code, I'm using  `.appendTo` and and its a normal html select

Comment: If correct, then you should be able to fix it with the suggestion in my previous comment not?

Comment: If it's your full code why can't i see `.appendTo` method? And the HTML?

Comment: @RensTillmann I switched to chosenjs, it doesn't have the same problem as selectize and it solved my other problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49158849/selectizejs-isnt-loading-the-options-correctly?noredirect=1#comment85323898_49158849. I'll leave this question here as a reference for other selectize users